# Корректность выражения "пойти с визитом"

Tags: плеоназм

Пойти к кому-либо (матросу, подруге) с визитом — не является ли данное выражение плеоназмом?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на плеоназм, и очень, но немного не дотягивает. Дело в том, что "с визитом" — это обычно про помещение, где кто-то находится, чаще всего — живёт (хоть даже временно). Но ведь можно и пойти к кому-то, кто ждёт на улице. То есть не всегда (но очень часто) "пойти к кому-либо" — это визит.

Answer (score 0):

Общеупотребительная лексика не является отчетливо определенной, как какая-нибудь инженерная лексика. Кто-нибудь сможет сказать, является ли визитом пойти к кому-либо домой и убить его, например? Никто не скажет вам ответа в таких ситуациях, поэтому никто не сможет сказать, что это плеоназм или какая-либо ошибка подобного рода.

Comment: Там "**к кому-либо**".

Comment: К кому-либо (матросу, подруге).

Comment: Аа, теперь ясна ваша мысль, но тогда скажут "пойти в чей-то дом", а если "пошёл к нему домой", то в гости (всё же с визитом).

Comment: Не очень понял, что вы имели ввиду. Слово ‟визит” говорят не только тогда, когда идут в гости. Когда люди идут по делу, то тоже говорят ‟нанести визит”.

Comment: Имею в виду то, что киллер не идёт к кому-то домой, а идёт в дом. Кто пошёл домой — тот гость (визитёр). Если не зашёл сначала поговорить, то это не визит. Таким образом, нельзя сказать, что и вор наносит визит.

Comment: Вот в том то и дело. Нигде такие тонкости значения не прописаны. Когда нож перестает быть ножом: когда лезвие 10см, 20см, 30см.? С лезвие 40 см нож уже меч, а с лезвием 25 см?

Comment: К тому же слово может приобретать различные фигуральные значения.

Comment: Изготовление оружия стандартизировано: https://razmery.info/dom/raznoe/razmery-nozhej-ohotnichih.html

Comment: Например, на заводах, на которых производят холодное оружие безусловно есть детальные и тонкие классификации любых видов ножей, как и среди каких-нибудь охотников. Было бы странно, если бы люди, производящие холодное оружие, не имели бы тонкой специальной терминологии. Но все это не имеет отношения к общеупотребительному слову ‟нож”. Регламент использования этого слова в головах у людей формируется не исходя из прочтения документации, а из наблюдения использования слова при обозначении объектов, которые в их обществе называют словом ‟нож”.

Comment: Речь о том, что в головах людей нет детальной стандартизации. Более детальная стандартизация может появится тогда, когда для общества будет крайне важно различать виды ножей. Тогда в обществе появится гораздо больше общеупотребительных слов, которые будут обозначать ножи, и тогда регламенты данных слов в головах у людей будут содержать гораздо больше тонких характеристик и отличий.

Comment: Наверно, дело во внешнем виде. Ведь можно сделать и гигантский нож (для великана).

Comment: Нож в руке великана назовут ‟гигантский нож”, так как данный нож будет значительно превышать допустимый диапазон по параметру размер для обозначения чего-то словом ‟нож”.

Comment: Ну да, но как поймут, что это нож, а не меч? Ведь он большой, даже больше меча. Поймут по внешнему виду (по форме).

Comment: По всевозможным параметрам.

Comment: Ну да, это и есть внешний вид.

Answer (score 0):

Так же, как и более расхожее сочетание "посетит с визитом", фраза корректна.

*Президент **посетит с визитом** Северную Уругвандию.*

Да, значения слов частично пересекаются, но "с визитом" уточняет характер посещения или цель похода к подруге или матросу.

Сравните: "Он пойдет к подруге на ужин", "Он пойдет к матросу драться", "Он пойдет к подруге помочь с домашним заданием", "Он пойдет к матросу с просьбой".